# Force the browser to download the latest version of a pdf

Tags: jquery, pdf, unique

I have a client who overwrites a new file every month via ftp. This file is linked in the website. When a user downloads the link, there's a change the cached version is shown instead of the latest version.

I would like to add a unique/random number to the link to force.

how can this be done with jquery?

```
<div class="extra_pdf_link">
<a href="http://www.website.com/lib/link-to-file.pdf">
</div>
```

wanted result:

```
<div class="extra_pdf_link">
<a href="http://www.website.com/lib/link-to-file.pdf?2390S">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `Math.random();` to generate a random value. This way everyone would always be downloading the latest version of the file in case it is cached by the browser.

Comment: Solution posted. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yar48rrx/1/

What you first want to do is generate a number. This number would be used to then add to the end of the existing href value, and that should do it.

**Try the following:**

```
var mynum = Math.floor((Math.random())*10000);

$(".extra_pdf_link a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '?' + mynum;
});
```

With the above code, you can do `console.log(mynum)` or `alert(mynum)` to see what the value for that page load is for `mynum`. That `console.log()` output or `alert()` dialog will show the value added to the end of `.extra_pdf_link a`.

This is more efficient (and much quicker) if done with server side code. I'm not sure if you are creating a static html application, or if you're using something like PHP, C#, etc.

Comment: And as a side node, some people may prefer generating the unique numerical value by generating the date and time. This approach is fine as well.